# how do i create API function for this Codeigniter function

Tags: php, api, codeigniter

This is a function from my todo app in codeigniter which takes $username as paramater and checks if it exists by checking the userid for that username if no id is returned it creates the user and returns the id of new user and if the username exists it simply returns the id.
I want to create an API function for this function, i am confused how do i do that

```
public function get_userid($username)
{

    $this->db->select('id');
    $this->db->from('user');
    $this->db->where("`username` = '".$username."'");
    $query = $this->db->get()->result;

    $count = count($query);
    if($count==0)
    {
        $this->create_user($username);
        return $this->get_userid($username);
    }

    return $query;
}
```

Comment: I'm confused too. Try to be more specific about your API structure

Comment: @claudio I am trying to make an APi which gets user id but in this function its also creating a user. I tried to make an API function but since there is a recursion in it for getting a user id after creating the user, it went on loop and creating thousands of NULL entries in the database. I am sorry if im not being specific im a beginner developer.

Comment: why not create a new function? why you want to use this one?

Comment: @claudio didn't know if thats a good practice. I was thinking about doing that. thanks

Comment: calling a function `get_userid` that also creates users and doesn't even return the id (but the query result) is definitely not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function :

```
public function call_get_userid()
{
    $username = $this->input->get('username');

    echo json_encode($this->get_userid($username));

}
```

and pass the username as GET parameter

> http://*base_url*/*controller*/call_get_userid?username=*username*

Answer (score 0):

Try doing something like this:

```
public function get_userid($username)
{
    $this->db->select('id');
    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $result = $this->db->get('user')->result;

    if ($result && ($row = $result->row())) {
        return $row['id'];
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

don't forget to change the function name.